# Domain API curl authenication

Tags: php, http, curl

http://domainapi.com/documentation/how-to-use-domainapi/some-generalities-about-domainapi/authentication.html

I read the whole API and still having problems with the authenication

```
$url = "api.domainapi.com/v1/availability/example.com";
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'login:password'); 
        curl_exec($ch);
```

**Error:**

```
  HTTP Status 401 -
    type Status report

    message

    description This request requires HTTP authentication ().
```

**Can anyone explain to me me how to succesfuly authenicate (i am getting authenication errors)?**

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: HTTP Status 401 -
type Status report

message

description This request requires HTTP authentication ().

Comment: What login credentials are you using to authenticate?

Comment: As far as I know there is no registratio/login system

Comment: well it won't work with the actual values 'login' and 'password'. Also the URL looks like an example too. You need to provide a real example (but omit any real credentials in your question).

Comment: Even the URL you reference indicates that it's just trying to show you how you would use the API, it's not actually an API itself. You need to actually try hitting a real API.

Comment: I dont know how to register, I guess I will try with an alternative API

Comment: which API are you trying to hit?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is asking about connecting to an API but doesn't reference a real API.

- The documentation you point to is just a general 'how to'
- the URL in your code is just an example (you need to try and hit a real API)
- the login details are just an example (you should be using real details when trying to connect)

As the site doesn't give any useful information about authentication you should contact them http://domainapi.com/contact.html

They should make it clear if you have to contact the individual provider for credentials, or if domainapi supply those credentials.